# Summing values from referenced starting and ending cells

Tags: excel

I have one row with week numbers from 1 to 52 in the cells B13 to BA13

In the row below I have a number representing that week's sales.

I want to be able to input the start week number and the end week number, and get the sum of the sales from the starting week to the ending week.

How can this be done?

Comment: Consider about using [SUMIFs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx)

Comment: Could you show us your Excel file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a combination of `SUM` and `OFFSET`.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Formula in `B19`:**

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B14,,C16-1,,C17-C16+1))
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Easiest to understand

Answer (score 3):

SUMIFS per @simco suggestion would look like this:

```
=SUMIFS(B14:BA14,B13:BA13,">="&C9,B13:BA13,"<="&C10)
```

[image]